# Restcomm jDiameter: Error creating SCTP socket

Tags: sctp, restcomm, diameter-protocol

I am trying to create a standalone SCTP diameter client using Jdiameter. The jar libraries I am using are *jdiameter-api-1.5.9.0-build538-SNAPSHOT* and *jdiameter-impl-1.5.9.0-build538-SNAPSHOT*

But I get this error **Unable to create server socket for LocalPeer 'client.test.com' at 127.0.0.1:55555 (org.mobicents.protocols.api.AssociationListener)**

It works fine with TCP. I tried to debug but couldn't figure out the problem. Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

SCTP will not work on windows systems. For linux systems, you might have to install the sctp stack. However, be aware that for some linux distributions you might run into strange issues with it, so e.g. that the port is still being blocked even after all server sockets, client sockets etc are closed and even the processes have been shut down or killed. In these cases, you need to wait about 5-10 minutes until the sctp stack recognizes that there is no one anymore who is interested in this port and releases it by itself.